# Tableau + Spark SQL Connector + Java Spark Data Frames

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, tableau-api

I need to perform BI analysis on some data using Tableau. The data is stored in a Cassandra database and there is a column with dynamic JSON data inside, which cannot be parsed directly by Tableau.

Spark jobs will be ran using Java, connecting to the Cassandra database and therefore performing the required calculations to map each JSON type to a new table, which is going to be stored.

I've managed to start a thrift-server and use Tableau to connect to it, no problem here

**PROBLEM:** Although I do actually store tables and I am able to see them in the Java output console, I cannot actually see the tables created when looking for them on Tableau connected to the Thrift Server.

After some reading, I've managed to find that both Thrift Server and these Spark Jobs need to be connected to the same remote hive, but I can't seem to find the settings I have to apply for these. This happens because the thrift-server shell script is executed in a context, and the Java code is executed in another (although in the same machine), so the HDFS directories are different, I guess.

Some code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf config = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("spark://Andres-MacBook-Air.local:7077")
            .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/tmp/spark-tests")
            .setAppName("tests");

    SparkContext ctx = new SparkContext(config);
    SparkSession session = new SparkSession(ctx);
    SQLContext sqlCtx = new SQLContext(session);

    Dataset<Row> emptyDataSet = session.createDataFrame(new ArrayList<>(), getSchema());
    emptyDataSet.show();


    sqlCtx.registerDataFrameAsTable(emptyDataSet, "tests");
    emptyDataSet.cache();

    System.out.println("*******");

    Dataset<Row> row = sqlCtx.sql("SHOW TABLES IN `default`");
    row.show();

    while (true) {

    }
}

private static StructType getSchema() {

    String schemaString = "column1 column2 column3 column4 column5";

    List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    StructField indexField = DataTypes.createStructField("column0", DataTypes.LongType, true);
    fields.add(indexField);

    for (String fieldName : schemaString.split(" ")) {
        StructField field = DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName, DataTypes.StringType, true);
        fields.add(field);
    }

    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

    return schema;
}
```

The spark-thrift server connects to the same spark master, and I am issuing the following command to start it:

```
sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --master spark://Andres-MacBook-Air.local:7077 --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/tmp/spark-tests --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000
```

Below are the following dependencies I am using in my Maven project:

```
    <dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Spark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>    

    <!-- Spark - Cassandra connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am using OSX and running spark locally: spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Get a mysql db (port 3306), start hive metastore process (port 9083), start hiveserver2 process (port 10000) then copy the hive-site.xml from hive folder to spark folder and start spark thrift server process (port 10002). The mysql is need ed to stores metadata (schema/table/column names, data types, partitions) for the hive tables.

These links can help:

https://mapr.com/docs/52/Spark/SparkSQLThriftServer.html
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_ig_hive_metastore_configure.html
https://heshamrafi.wordpress.com/2017/08/16/install-hive-and-configure-mysql-for-metadata/
https://www.guru99.com/installation-configuration-hive-mysql.html
https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2016/08/22/how-to-run-queries-on-spark-sql-using-jdbc-via-thrift-server/